# java - establishing new variables based on input

Tags: java, object, methods, syntax

So, the program calls for a bowling game. Once you ask how many players, every player gets 2 throws to knock down 10 pins (simulated by random numbers). If you knock them all down with the first go, then you get 20 points, if on your second go you get 15 points, other than that score = throw 1 + throw 2.

The tricky part for me has been getting each player to alternate frames (2 throws = 1 frame, up to ten frames per player) while the program keeps track of everyone's score! I thought I had it with this but the randoms just add up ill post the output on the bottom

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bowling {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        Game aNew = new Game();
        int player;
        int i;
        int j;
        int nPlay;



        System.out.print("How many players are there?: ");
        nPlay = input.nextInt();
            for (j = 1; j<= 10; j++) {
                for (i = 1; i <= nPlay; i++ ){
                     player = i; // i tried player i = new Player() but get error "value
                     aNew.getScore(player); // already used in scope""
                }
            }
```

Games class:

```
import java.lang.Math;

    public class Game {
    int score = 0;
    int player;
    int ran1;
    int ran2;

    public Game() {
    }

    public int getScore(int player){
        ran1 = (int) (9 * Math.random());
        ran2 = (int) (((10 - ran1)) * Math.random());

        if (ran1 == 10){
            score += 20;
        } else if (ran1 + ran2 == 10){
            score += 15;
        } else {
            score += ran1 + ran2;
        }   System.out.println("Player " + player + " score is: " + score + "\n");
        System.out.println("ran1: " + ran1 + "  ran2: " + ran2);
        return score;
    }
}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player {
   /** this class is not doing anything, however i would like for an object to store a score for every player to keep track if that is possible?*/ 
    int score;

    public Player (){
        int score;
    }
}
```

Output: (suspicious how every time the last player had the highest or I would have never noticed it didn't work!)

```
How many players are there?: 2

Player 1 score is: 2

ran1: 1  ran2: 1
Player 2 score is: 11

ran1: 8  ran2: 1
Player 1 score is: 16

ran1: 5  ran2: 0
Player 2 score is: 21

ran1: 4  ran2: 1
Player 1 score is: 29

ran1: 8  ran2: 0
Player 2 score is: 35

ran1: 5  ran2: 1
Player 1 score is: 40

ran1: 3  ran2: 2
Player 2 score is: 47

ran1: 6  ran2: 1
Player 1 score is: 56

ran1: 8  ran2: 1
Player 2 score is: 61

ran1: 5  ran2: 0
Player 1 score is: 68

ran1: 7  ran2: 0
Player 2 score is: 77

ran1: 8  ran2: 1
Player 1 score is: 85

ran1: 4  ran2: 4
Player 2 score is: 90

ran1: 4  ran2: 1
Player 1 score is: 97

ran1: 7  ran2: 0
Player 2 score is: 103

ran1: 3  ran2: 3
Player 1 score is: 107

ran1: 4  ran2: 0
Player 2 score is: 114

ran1: 3  ran2: 4
Player 1 score is: 121

ran1: 7  ran2: 0
Player 2 score is: 125

ran1: 0  ran2: 4
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i just can't figure out how break the random#s into groups of players, keep track of score, and print them correctly based on input of number of players and create new variables for their scores without breaking the sytax of java, any suggestions are appreciated?

Comment: I don't want the scores to add up, i need each players score seperated.

Comment: it seems to me like your Game object should contain a collection type of players. Initialize a List<> or some other collection type to the size matching the number of players, then fill it with new players. then when you do the getScore for a player, make it accept either an index (int) or a Player type, and modify the players scores <- thats important because youre modifying the variable score in your game class and not the player class currently.

Comment: Thanks this is from an exercise from a "guide to programming in java " you would think they would teach lists and arrays before giving this problem but they havent so im only allowed basic object oriented development for now. Im thinking something along the lines of two objects. A game and player object with createNewPLayer() method that includes a new score for the each player player but im trying to figure out how they are going to still keep track of scores for individual players when its called

Comment: If you follow (however closely you want) the example I wrote below, the scores will be maintained in seperate instances of the Player class. So as you Create a new Player like  
    Player newPlayer = new Player("PlayersName"); 
    Game.addPlayer(newPlayer);
the Game object will then have a collection of players, each with their own names and scores for you to work with.

Comment: Also, if allowing the user to set the number of players from 1-N where N has no limits, it would be awefully difficult to do what youre trying to do without collections, if not impossible. Now if you had a fixed maximum, or number of players, it wouldnt be so difficult.

Comment: haha the whole time (literally ive sat on this problem for a good four plus hours) questioning my ability to program but i guess this way just isnt practical, thats prolly why im getting so frustrated. i thought it was me. thanks a bunch tho @MarkW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Player class is currently doing nothing. Fix this by first making accessors and modifiers for your Player.score variable like this. Maybe even give them a name:

```
public class Player {
     int score;
     String name;
     public Player(String name) { this.name = name; }
     public void getName() { return this.name; }
     public void setScore(int newScore) { score = newScore; }
     public int getScore() { return score; }

}
```

now your game class should have a collection type of players like

```
public class Game {
    List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
    public Game() {
    }
    public void AddPlayer(Player p) {
        players.add(p);
    }
    public Player getPlayer(int index) { return players.get(index); }
    public void playerBowl(Player p) {
        ran1 = (int) (9 * Math.random());
        ran2 = (int) (((10 - ran1)) * Math.random());

        if (ran1 == 10){
            p.setScore(p.getScore() +20);
        } else if (ran1 + ran2 == 10){
            p.setScore(p.getScore() +15);
        } else {
            p.setScore(p.getScore() + ran1 + ran2);
        }   System.out.println("Player " + p.getName() + " score is: " + p.getScore() + "\n");
        System.out.println("ran1: " + ran1 + "  ran2: " + ran2);
    }
}
```

Ill leave the main for you to figure out :D. Sorry if the syntax is a little off, I wrote it in the edit window :/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. lists are another 100 pages from this chapter in this book(which im starting to question the usefullness of). so im going to keep trying this way if nothing else ill skip a few chapters haha

Comment: no problem man, I love helping the new guy. FYI, doing this without collections is just a waste of time :P

Comment: haha @mark well thanks for making me not want to hate myself - sincerely new guy

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your troubles start here:

```
player = i; // i tried player i = new Player() but get error "value
aNew.getScore(player); // already used in scope""
```

The correct way would be:

```
Player i = new Player(); //mind the capital!
```

For the rest: You would probably want to use a List of Players and initialize this list once you know how many players there are. Finally, the getScore function should not modify the score variable in the Game class, but rather the score variable of a Player (with player.score = 20). You need to know your players in your Game class, but you can do this in several ways: pass a player as an argument to getScore, or pass the whole list of players at an earlier point.

All in all, there is quite a bit of code to rewrite for you, but I'm sure playing with this code will be very educational.